# How to set dialog to show in full screen?

Tags: android, android-fullscreen

I have a **GridView** and i want to make an implémentation of a dialog, on which
the picture that i have selected should display in full screen.

so how can i make the dialog shows in a full screen mode ?
thanks!

Comment: If you want to use a FULL SCREEN `Dialog`, why not just use the default `ACTION_VIEW` `Intent` for image files?

Comment: sorry I mean almost full screen or full image

Comment: In conjunction with answer to willytate if you have to dialog then use android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen in theme

Comment: This might help

http://stackoverflow.com/a/2700683/1118886

Comment: I do NOT understand why this question get closed. Annoying. Have a suggestion, but can't post. Kudos to @Andrew Barber!!! -.-

Comment: @MartinPfeffer i also have a suggestion for future user but question closed Andrew Barber is not from android community. this is really a simple question new android developers always curious about this. this question should be open again for better answers and future users

Answer (score 270):

try

```
Dialog dialog=new Dialog(this,android.R.style.Theme_Black_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen)
```

Comment: For this to work for me I had to use android.R.style.Theme_Black_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen

Comment: `Call requires API level 11`

Comment: @LuisA.Florit try Theme_Black_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen

Comment: What about fullscreen _with_ a titlebar?

Comment: When I do this (using `DialogFragment`) I see the status bar color is killed by the dialog, the whole screen is the dialog's background color. Does anyone know of a workaround? I tried setting the statusBarColor of the dialog's window, to no effect. P.S.: navigation bar color gets killed too.

Comment: But it gets black color as background how to change it?

Comment: still shows a gap where the statusbar should be...

Comment: you could use any theme with Fullscreen at the end of it, for me android.R.style.Theme_Holo_NoActionBar_Fullscreen worked the best, Theme_Black adds backgrounds to my EditTexts.

Comment: @Ahmed Salem  Tnx You saved my time. +1 vote for u

Comment: In kotlin it is: `dialog = Dialog(context!!, android.R.style.Theme_Black_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen)`

Comment: know its changed to         myAppAdsDialog=new Dialog(this,android.R.style.Theme_Black_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);

Comment: For fullscreen Dialog with titlebar you can use android.R.style.Theme_Black_NoTitleBar

Answer (score 110):

based on [this link](http://crintsoft.com/blog/?p=10) , the correct answer (which i've tested myself) is:

put this code in the constructor or the `onCreate()` method of the dialog:

```
getWindow().setLayout(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
```

in addition , set the style of the dialog to :

```
<style name="full_screen_dialog">
    <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation.Dialog</item>
    <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">stateUnspecified|adjustPan</item>
</style>
```

this could be achieved via the constructor , for example :

```
public FullScreenDialog(Context context)
{
  super(context, R.style.full_screen_dialog);
  ...
```

---

EDIT: an alternative to all of the above would be to set the style to `android.R.style.ThemeOverlay` and that's it.

EDIT2: To support material library, add Gradle dependency to app(module) `build.gradle` file

```
implementation "com.google.android.material:material:$material_version"
```

Then set dialog's theme to `R.style.ThemeOverlay_MaterialComponents`

Comment: With my try, this one is the only work one. `android.R.style.ThemeOverlay` is the key.

Comment: @Yeung I wonder if `ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents` is also suitable. Can you please check?

Comment: Tried. It works, but don't know it is useful or not as I am developing with an old Android 5 device.

Comment: @Yeung I think it's better than what I wrote, then. Supports new material library. Can you please write me what exactly you did, so that I could update my answer ? Or maybe you could edit mine?

Comment: When deal with old issue, just found this also has reference value `getDialog().getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(any bg color));` will "expand" the dialog's width to fullscreen which no need to set theme `android.R.style.ThemeOverlay` . Notice that for "width" only.

Comment: For me `ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents` was enough. Thanks.

Answer (score 67):

The easiest way I found

```
Dialog dialog=new Dialog(this,android.R.style.Theme_Black_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.frame_help);
        dialog.show();
```

Comment: cant change background color, still black

Answer (score 47):

**EDIT** Until such time as StackOverflow allows us to version our answers, this is an answer that works for Android 3 and below. Please don't downvote it because it's not working for you now, because it definitely works with older Android versions.

---

You should only need to add one line to your `onCreateDialog()` method:

```
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    //all other dialog stuff (which dialog to display)

    //this line is what you need:
    dialog.getWindow().setFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    return dialog;
}
```

Comment: Why I can't use FLAG_FULLSCREEN

Comment: Well, that's hard to say - Did you import LayoutParams? Is your layout  xml set to either fill_parent or match_parent?

Comment: use android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN

Comment: ERROR: `FLAG_FULLSCREEN cannot be resolved or is not a field`

Comment: It's possible that this answer is getting out of date - it might not work for android 4.0 and up.

Comment: @CaspNZ In android 4.0+, you should override the `DialogFragment`s `onCreateDialog` method. This way, everything is cool. ;-)

Comment: This was driving me nuts, whenever I created the Dialog the top region was clipped although it seems the window was actually fully sized (e.g. the window background was also clipped). I set LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN after requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE) but before setContentView()

Comment: you need to import like: import android.view.WindowManager;

Comment: this not worked for me .... in api 18 ... android studio emulator

Comment: This is a very old answer. It's possible that it no longer works in newer versions of the API

Answer (score 45):

```
dialog = new Dialog(getActivity(),android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.loading_screen);
    Window window = dialog.getWindow();
    WindowManager.LayoutParams wlp = window.getAttributes();

    wlp.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
    wlp.flags &= ~WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND;
    window.setAttributes(wlp);
    dialog.getWindow().setLayout(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    dialog.show();
```

try this.

Comment: MATCH_PARENT worked for me.