# Open a Custom Dialog on Click of a ListView Item Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I am trying to open a custom dialog box that cover the full interface of the device .But I don't know it is throwing exception Please check my code and help me to solve this issue.

**On click of the listview item**

```
data.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
              @Override
              public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
                passengerInformationPopup();

              }
    });

**The Function to open the Dialog**



public void passengerInformationPopup() {
    final Dialog dialog= new Dialog(getBaseContext());
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.passenger_details_dialog); 
    String[] tittlearray ={"Mr.","Mrs.","Ms"};
    Spinner tittleSpinner = (Spinner) dialog.findViewById(R.id.Tittle);
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, tittlearray); 

    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    tittleSpinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    dialog.show();
}
```

**Exception**

```
08-14 16:39:50.338: E/AndroidRuntime(30294): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-14 16:39:50.338: E/AndroidRuntime(30294): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
08-14 16:39:50.338: E/AndroidRuntime(30294):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:656)
08-14 16:39:50.338: E/AndroidRuntime(30294):    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:328)
08-14 16:39:50.338: E/AndroidRuntime(30294):    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:226)
08-14 16:39:50.338: E/AndroidRuntime(30294):    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:151)
08-14 16:39:50.338: E/AndroidRuntime(30294):    at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:277)
08-14 16:39:50.338: E/AndroidRuntime(30294):    at com.example.userdetails.MainActivity.passengerInformationPopup(MainActivity.java:181)
08-14 16:39:50.338: E/AndroidRuntime(30294):    at com.example.userdetails.MainActivity$5.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:149)
08-14 16:39:50.338: E/AndroidRuntime(30294):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
08-14 16:39:50.338: E/AndroidRuntime(30294):    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1114)
08-14 16:39:50.338: E/AndroidRuntime(30294):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2937)
08-14 16:39:50.338: E/AndroidRuntime(30294):    at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3695)
08-14 16:39:50.338: E/AndroidRuntime(30294):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
08-14 16:39:50.338: E/AndroidRuntime(30294):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-14 16:39:50.338: E/AndroidRuntime(30294):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
08-14 16:39:50.338: E/AndroidRuntime(30294):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4987)
08-14 16:39:50.338: E/AndroidRuntime(30294):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-14 16:39:50.338: E/AndroidRuntime(30294):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-14 16:39:50.338: E/AndroidRuntime(30294):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:821)
08-14 16:39:50.338: E/AndroidRuntime(30294):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
08-14 16:39:50.338: E/AndroidRuntime(30294):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: use activity context `Dialog dialog= new Dialog(ActivityName.this)`

Comment: @Raghunandan i want this dialog to open on the full page how could i do that

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6329360/how-to-set-dialog-to-show-with-full-screen

Comment: @Raghunandan i have done this final Dialog dialog=  new Dialog(this,android.R.style.Theme_Dark_NoTitleBar_FullScreen);but is is showing the error that Theme_Dark_NoTitleBar_FullScreen cannot be resolved or is not a field

Comment: use full screen theme. check the docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Activity Context

```
     final Dialog dialog= new Dialog(ActivityName.this);
```

To know when to use activity context

[When to call activity context OR application context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298731/when-to-call-activity-context-or-application-context)

From the comments

[How to set dialog to show with full screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6329360/how-to-set-dialog-to-show-with-full-screen)

Edit:

From Dianne Hackborn suggestion

Give its constructor a non-dialog theme, such as `android.R.style.Theme` or `android.R.style.Theme_Light`.

Look @ the themes

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/res/res/values/themes.xml.

More info @

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/NDFo9pF8sHY

```
   Dialog dialog=new Dialog(ActivityName.this,android.R.style.Theme);
```

Comment: i have done this final Dialog dialog= new Dialog(this,android.R.style.Theme_Dark_NoTitleBar_FullScreen);but is is showing the error that Theme_Dark_NoTitleBar_FullScreen cannot be resolved or is not a field

Comment: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/res/res/values/themes.xml.

Comment: i am not getting please help me on this i am trying to add the theme in my style but it is shwoing the error

Comment: @Gaurav https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/NDFo9pF8sHY. define styles in styles.xml and set the same to your dialog. use the ones in the link i provided above.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
final Dialog dialog= new Dialog(getApplicationcontext()); OR  final Dialog dialog= new Dialog(YOUR_ACTIVITY.this);
```

instead of

```
final Dialog dialog= new Dialog(getBaseContext());
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
final Dialog dialog= new Dialog(YOUR_ACTIVITY.this);
```

instead of

```
final Dialog dialog= new Dialog(getBaseContext());
```