# progress bar not showing in full screen into custom dialog

Tags: android, android-dialog, android-progressbar

In Java file:

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(Dashboard.this, R.style.FullHeightDialog);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.progress_dialog);
dialog.show();
```

progress_dialog.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.xorin.ress.gprogressbar.SmoothProgressBar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pbar"
    style="@style/GNowProgressBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:indeterminate="true" />
```

output comes like:

[image]

I want to display center progress bar with full width which is currently not displaying..

Comment: May be, this is usefull for you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6329360/how-to-set-dialog-to-show-with-full-screen .

Comment: @Shvet no, its not working..

Answer (score 0):

use ProgressDialog like

```
Object localObject = new ProgressDialog(getParent());
    ((ProgressDialog) localObject).setTitle("");
    ((ProgressDialog) localObject).setMessage("Please wait...");
    ((ProgressDialog) localObject).setCancelable(true);
    ((ProgressDialog) localObject)
            .setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener()      {
                public void onCancel(
                        DialogInterface paramAnonymousDialogInterface) { }
```