# Android AlertDialog.Builder fullscreen

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

How to set the `AlertDialog.Builder` to fullscreen(*see Attachment* taken from Google drive)?

I am not asking about `android.app.Dialog`, i am asking about `android.app.AlertDialog`.

Any code example appreciated,

Thanks,

[image]

Comment: You can make `Dialog Activity`. It will be fullscreen.

Comment: Check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6329360/how-to-set-dialog-to-show-with-full-screen