# Show dialog infront of keyboard

Tags: android, android-dialog

I m using `adjustResize` for my main `Activity` in Android app. When dialog are shown they are also adjusted to resize. But I need the dialog to be full screen like;

[image]

I tried to use `getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);` but this is not helpful. How to get it to work?

Comment: see more code here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6329360/how-to-set-dialog-to-show-with-full-screen

Answer (score 1):

After some research, found the solution. To display dialog in front of keyboard following flag is needed to be set on `Dialog` instance;

`dialog.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM,
         WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM);`

Reference: [Android API Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM)

Comment: I LOVE THIS ANSWER. Thank you so much!! I ended up answering my own question too thanks to this wonderful answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63596366/prevent-bottomsheetdialogfragment-from-hiding-keyboard/63608679#63608679