# Should I use a dialog or a popup window as the initial login screen?

Tags: android, dialog, popupwindow

Quite a simple one but I don's see any documentation anywhere. The only place I have found it is in developer.android there is an example for a login in a dialog. As I said it is for the initial login of my app so it needs to be full-screen which is an issue for dialogs as it doesn't seem possible without using an older (pre-Ice cream sandwich I think) theme which includes older looking editTexts.
Any guidance on the matter would be great, thanks.

(Below is a comparison of the two types of edit text, I am forced to use the first on the login page to allow a dialog to be full-screen)

[image: EditTexts]

Comment: Can you tell the difference between a Dialog and a `popup window`?

Comment: if I could get the dialog to be fullscreen using a current sdk I dont think so.

Comment: How to set a Dialog in full screen: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6329360/how-to-set-dialog-to-show-with-full-screen

Comment: I have used this solution but it forces an older api that makes the editTexts look awfull and inconsistent.

Comment: Probably, you didn't use it correctly.

Comment: The image in my question shows the edit text that you HAVE to use if you use thay method of making a dialog fullscreen where as rhe one below it is what I would like to use.

Comment: Still I don't understand the matter... `android:layout_width="match parent"` and you are happily in full width. There are different answers to that question.

Comment: That doesnt work. Also I just want to kniw what the convention/ general consensus is on the matter

Answer (score 0):

You may have a look at DialogFragment to do dialog customizations. For edittext, you can always set custom borders by creating a drawable .xml and setting it as background in Edittext.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:thickness="0dp" android:shape="rectangle">
<stroke android:width="2dp"
       android:color="#00cc33"/>
<corners android:radius="10dp"/>
<padding android:left="10dp"
       android:top="5dp"   
       android:right="10dp"
       android:bottom="5dp"/>
</shape>
```

In your layout xml,

```
<EditText
  ...
...
android:background="@drawable/my_edittext_border"/>
```

Comment: I realise that I can customise the edit texts but I would like to use the android default across my whole app.