# Force Full Screen Input to EditText

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment, android-dialog

I am trying to force a EditText which is in Dialog to show up full screen input aka extract ui.
Or at least i need a solution because keyboard is overlapping dialog.

Thanks for helps.

Comment: create custom dialog http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6329360/how-to-set-dialog-to-show-with-full-screen

Comment: i need full screen input screen. Not the dialog

Comment: You need to show some efforts and sample code before we start helping you.
Post some images and sample code.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, your target is to have EditText similar to default landscape implementation.

There is no standard solution for this case: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/Wihil_srtN4

As a workaround you can implement OnFocusChangeListener in your EditText(or OnClickListener - depends on IME options of other dialog fields) and launch new Activity (witch is designed to show keyboard and full-screen EditText) when user is going to enter text.