# PopupWindow inside Dialog

Tags: android, android-dialog, android-popupwindow

I have a problem with `PopupWindow` class used inside a `Dialog`.

The code works fine and the popup does show, but it is clipped to the content area of the `Dialog`. In my case, the popup can contain quite a bit of text, which makes it look weird, being clipped suddenly at the bottom of the `Dialog` :-(

Here is a little presentation:

[image]

**Any hints how to make the popup draw inside the whole window, not just the `Dialog` frame?**

I already tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22912507/3231532), but it breaks the `Dialog` styling, making it fill the whole screen and requiring lots of tricky fixes, so I would rather not use it.