# view full screen image when item from recycler view clicks

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-recyclerview

I am new to android.I have a RecyclerView which shows list of images from a json.I want to do showing image full screen when item from RecyclerView clicks.Also it should be able to zoom in and out.(Like gallery).Zooming functionalty is done using Photoview Library.But viewing full screen a item is not done.Adapter class code is attached below.Please anyone help me to do this.

```
 @Override
 public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final MyHolder myHolder = (MyHolder) holder;
    DataFish current = data.get(position);

    // load image into imageview using glide
    Glide.with(context).load(current.flagimage)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
            .error(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
            .into(myHolder.imageView);
    myHolder.imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });


}
```

I want to add the code for view full screen in this onclick.

Comment: First get the bitmap of the image when user click on the item and then on the next activity/or fragment where you want to show , then set that bitmap on the imageview . Hope you get the idea

Comment: Can i show the imageview  using dialog without moving to next fragment/activity?

Comment: you can follow this link  to get the dilog full screen :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6329360/how-to-set-dialog-to-show-with-full-screen

Answer (score 6, accepted):

follow this steps

> create a new Activity like this and retrive url

**LAYOUT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/myImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Activity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    ImageView myImage;
    String url = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        url = getIntent().getStringExtra("image_url");

        myImage = findViewById(R.id.myImage);
        Glide.with(this).load(url)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                .error(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                .into(myImage);
    }


}
```

> When use click om recyclerview item than pass the url to that activity using intent

```
 myHolder.imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent= new Intent(context,MainActivity.this);
            intent.putExtra("image_url",current.flagimage);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

> you can use [**`PhotoView`**](https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView) for zooming  `ImageView`

**`PhotoView`** aims to help produce an easily usable implementation of a zooming Android `ImageView`.

Comment: You missed the Pinch to Zoom.

Comment: @Woods yup but the op has already said that  `Zooming functionalty is done using Photoview Library`

Comment: Sorry Nilesh, I misunderstood the question. However I would be great to add it.

Comment: @Woods thanks  no need to say sorry i have just updated my ans

Comment: Yep. Good Day Nilesh !

Comment: hi Nilesh. Do you have any knowledge about other library like PhotoView library. I was using it but found some bug on Zooming image it is flickering sometimes.

Comment: Thanks Nilesh ! I'll try it.

Comment: @Woods also check this tutorial if you don't wont use third party lib for zoom image-view https://www.androidhive.info/2013/09/android-fullscreen-image-slider-with-swipe-and-pinch-zoom-gestures/ there is custom class for imageview `TouchImageView.java` for zooming

Comment: Well I already went thru it. Using library is just for shorten the code length or I'll get messed up ! Thanks. Good day Nilesh !

Comment: @Woods happy to help you

Comment: @PRAMESHBHALALA happy to help you my friend