# How to pass data one textview to another textview inside activity

Tags: android

I am trying to show data in toolbar. I have `recyclerview` where I set movies name. when I click any movie name, the name show in toolbar. I defined the `onclick` method in adapter class.
 [This is adapter class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7aeqP.png)

Comment: **Welcome to stackoverflow** Have a look **[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)** And Also you need to share your code as **`TEXT`**

Comment: This will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50127376/view-full-screen-image-when-item-from-recycler-view-clicks/50127439#50127439

Answer (score 2):

Make public method in adapter class and call that method in onClick

ExampleAdapter.java

```
 holder.tvMovie.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                    onSelectMovie(list.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getname());
                }
            }
        });
 public void onSelectMovie(String movieName)
    {

    }
```

Override onSelectMovie method where you call the adapter constructor

```
exampleAdapter = new ExampleAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onSelectMovie(String movieName) {
                super.onSelectImage(movieName);
                setTitle(movieName);
            }
        };
```