# Creating an Activity as instance?

Tags: java, android

I have created an pop up window that I can use to show important messages in my app. The code for this are written in PopActivity.

Here is my code:

```
public class PopActivity extends Activity {
private WorkOutClass the_workout_class = new WorkOutClass();

private TextView repTextField, setsTextField;
private Button den_knappen;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pop);

    repTextField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.repetitionID);
    setsTextField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.setsID);
    den_knappen = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonID);

    repTextField.setText("Reps : " + String.valueOf(the_workout_class.getReps()));
    setsTextField.setText("Sets: " +String.valueOf(the_workout_class.getSets()));



    DisplayMetrics thePopUpWindow = new DisplayMetrics();

    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(thePopUpWindow);

    int width = thePopUpWindow.widthPixels;
    int height = thePopUpWindow.heightPixels;

    getWindow().setLayout((int)(width*.8), (int)(height*.7));

    WindowManager.LayoutParams params = getWindow().getAttributes();
    params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
    params.x = 0;
    params.y = 20;


    getWindow().setAttributes(params);

    den_knappen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            the_workout_class.increaseReps();
            repTextField.setText("Reps : " + String.valueOf(the_workout_class.getReps()));
            setsTextField.setText("Sets: " +String.valueOf(the_workout_class.getSets()));


        }
    });



}}
```

My question is though: If i want to use the same type of pop-up window somewhere else in my app which provide a different message, is there a way I can just copy this to use it? Or do I need to create new file such as PopActivity2, PopActivity3 etc etc.?

Thanks for answer.

Comment: I suggest to pass your text/data via `Intent`. This would be something worth looking at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2091482/180538

Comment: What Warren suggested is the reasonable approach. Try creating a generic pop activity that you can pass the data you wish for. If you do not wish to pass the Text through an `Intent`, you can also try Inheritance.

Comment: for pop-up window make a separate class where you write you pop-up code and that can be used in any activity/fragment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds to me that what you really need is a `Dialog`. You can create your own layout and texts for a dialog, and then use it where ever you need it. These links can help you with that:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs

[How do I display an alert dialog on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115758/how-do-i-display-an-alert-dialog-on-android)

[How to set dialog to show in full screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6329360/how-to-set-dialog-to-show-in-full-screen)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your data via Intent when you start your Activity like

```
// in previous activity
Intent intent = new Intent(this, PopActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("first", "your message")
startActivity(intent);


// in PopActivity
String message = getIntent().getStringExtra("first")
```

and use this as the message your need. You can pass more data if you want. Best would be to define a constant for the name ("first") with a better name and use this on both Activities ;-)

Comment: Someone suggested me to create the popUp as a class, and someone else suggested me to create a singleton. Now I am confused.. which choise is the best?

Comment: You typically don't need a singleton.